# Free web or desktop (OSX/Windows) software to allow free video conferencing for large groups (10+)

Tags: web-apps, video, communication, video-conferencing

Which free software allows many (10+) people to video conference for free?

It must:

- Be easy to sign up to
- Be free for many-user video conferencing (whether or not it charges for other things doesn't matter)
- Not require a credit card to use it
- Work on Mac / Windows
- Be easy enough for a layperson to sign up to, install and use (e.g. a github repository wouldn't meet this hurdle since a layperson wouldn't know how to install/run it)
- Must be usable from Desktop computer (i.e. from Chrome or another browser, or a desktop software variant)

#### What I know so far

- **Skype** allows 1 on 1 video conferencing - not sure about groups? Also not sure if it's free
- **Microsoft Teams** allows large group video conferencing, but I'm almost certain it's not free
- **Viber**?
- **Whatsapp**?
- **Facebook live video** (is only one-way video?)
- **Google hangouts** is free for 2 users, is it free for many users?
- **Periscope** (only one-way video)
- **Zoom** (many to many video, not sure if free?)
- Others?

#### Note

The motivation for this question is in the current situation many are missing out on vital services because the providers simply aren't familiar with options for providing vital services to groups digitally (think: physiotherapy, some medical appointments, some tuition, some fitness classes).

Answer (score 1):

Another to add to your list is Jitsi: https://jitsi.org/.  It meets all the requirements you have listed and in addition works on Linux, Android and iOS.